How to visually indicate that a default rule has been overridden?
Background
I'm designing a new feature for a B2B web app that allows restaurant staff to split non-cash tips among multiple workers. For example, restaurant patrons leave servers a tip, but servers need to pay out a portion of their tips to other people like bartenders and bussers. Most checks follow the default rule for tip splitting set by the restaurant admin ahead of time. For example by default, 75% of the check's tip could be allocated to the server, 20% to the bartender, and 5% to the busser.
However, admins have the ability to create a custom tip split adjustment to override the default rule. For example they'd want to do this if the table had multiple servers due to a shift change. Admins can view a table that lists all the checks for the day, and there should be some visual indication of which checks have been impacted by a custom override or adjustment. Just something relatively subtle to allow admins to identify those rows at a glance. This indicator can't add to the width of the table, as it's already extremely wide. Admins can click on a table row to view more detailed information about it, including the details of the custom tip adjustment.
What are some options to do this? Is there any other software you can think of that displays something like this that I can turn to for inspiration?
What I've tried so far
Option 1: pie chart icon with tooltip on hover

Option 2: corner triangle with tooltip on hover.
I got this idea from spreadsheet software that adds a triangle to the upper left corner of cells when there's more information there, such as a comment or error.

Option 3: a left border on affected rows with visible explanatory text

Option 4: a different row background color along with visible explanatory text


If the user is going to only be the admin (who I assume would go through some onboarding / training, either method would work). It seems like a low impact action that they can hover/ click on to know more about anyways. So, purely from an aesthetic point of view, I think the spreadsheet like triangles is the best approach. It does not take up space (like the icons), nor mimics selected row behavior like the left border and diff row background. (which I believe would be confusing).

@TDsouza Yes, that's a good point about options 3 and 4 mimicking selected row behavior. My team brought that up as a concern as well, so I can probably rule those out.

@TDsouza please make your comment an answer so that I can upvote it.

You could put a simple text indicator next to the tip. That’s the number being affected, the CC Tip? It looks like there’s space for it.


One option to visually denote that some overrides are in place without taking up additional space would be to use italic text for the columns that have had any of the defaults overridden.
This will have little or no impact on the column widths, avoids having an additional column and has the advantage of being able to be carried over into hard copy if necessary. You could also have the hover behaviour to tell the user what has been overridden.

I think this is a bit broad topic since it needs details in many levels for used softwares etc. But I'll be narrowing down other than generally speaking for the parts that presumably having ongoing precudures already.
First of all, I'd prefer using separate accounts for all people authorized to enter orders. That means, either it's via a personal card or tablet/phone used by each employee to enter those order,  it will have the information whose taking those orders instead of tracking shift changes.
That prevents many misleading conceptions even if someone can't take an order of specific table when (s)he is in the shift. It can be easily tracked afterwards.
Then the important part is to show it as you already suggested couple ways to do it. Personally, I find it preference of choice but the option more appealing for me is,

Option 4: a different row background color along with visible explanatory text

